# Visa to Germany on hold

Tags: visas, schengen, germany

I have a specific situation to clarify. I submitted an application for a short-term visa for a short internship in Germany. I was told, however, that I need a new work permit due to an issue with the dates.

The visa application has been on hold already for 3 weeks already. They called me last week to ask whether the new work permit is ready or not, but the company told me the work permit needs 4-5 weeks to be ready.

Right now, the visa is on hold. How long can a visa application be held in the embassy? If they maybe refuse my visa before the new work permit is ready, can I submit again directly a new visa application?

Comment: What you refer to "they", are you speaking of the embassy? ("They" called me.) And the "company" mentioned are your employers in Germany, correct?

Comment: yes exactly sorry didn't see that

Comment: What's your citizenship, just in case it matters?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify comments, putting on hold.